# sharepoint - get items from lists in multiple webs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Let's say I have a site level feature that has a content type, and a web level feature that has a list instance with items of the previously mentioned content type. If I enable the web feature for 100+ different webs, so I get 100+ lists from the same list instance definition and content type, what's the fastest way to get items from all those lists? Iterating through the webs and getting list items for each list one by one is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Method Below.

1. [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way (and only way in my opinion) is to use the search engine.
You can do queries like "contenttype:document" to search for document across lists.